# Keras multiclass classificator error with validation data and validation labels: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a multi-class classificator for 24 classes with Keras using VGG16 bottleneck features and a small fully connected model on top.

At first I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html adapting it to multiclass, then I got the error and tried to use this other tutorial's code: http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/08/bottleneck-features-multi-class-classification-keras.html and got the exact same error. I cannot figure out what the problem is!

The error I get is : " **ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 12768 input samples and 12782 target samples.** "

Basically I have two folders, train and validation. The train folder has 52992 png images, the validation folder as 12782 png images. My batch size is 16.

Here is the code in `save_bottleneck_features()` where I save the validation data (this function is called before the `train_top_model()` function):

```
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

nb_validation_samples = len(generator.filenames)

predict_size_validation = int(
    math.ceil(nb_validation_samples / batch_size))


bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
    generator, predict_size_validation)

np.save('bottleneck_features_validation.npy',
        bottleneck_features_validation)
```

And here is the code in `train_top_model()` where I calculate the validation labels:

```
generator_top = datagen_top.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode= 'categorical',
    shuffle=False)

nb_validation_samples = len(generator_top.filenames)

validation_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_validation.npy')

validation_labels = generator_top.classes
validation_labels = np.array(
     [0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
validation_labels = to_categorical(
   validation_labels, num_classes=num_classes)
```

`print predict_size_validation` prints 798
`print nb_validation_samples` prints 12782
`print len(validation_data)` prints 12768
`print len(validation_labels)` prints 12782

Train data and train labels are calculated in the same way but they are OK.

I think that maybe the problem is with `predict_size_validation`, and that 12782 is not divisible by 16.

Thank you!!!

Comment: When I run `int(math.ceil(12782 / 16))`, I get as a result 799 instead of 798. Is it possible that you used some different version of your code?

Comment: No I am sure this is the code. I tried printing nb_validation_samples and it is 12782 !  I also tried to print `print int(math.ceil((12782/16)))` and it prints 798

Comment: That is very odd. After all, `12782 / 16` is exactly 798.875 and thus `math.ceil` of this number should give 799 and not 798!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2, which I assume you are using given the comments, the division of two integers gives the integer division by default. This means that `12782 / 16 == 798` (in python 3, this is equivalent to `12782 // 16`) instead of `12782 / 16 == 798.875` as is the case in python 3.

In order to resolve this issue, you should make sure that one of the numbers in the division is a float in order to get the correct behaviour, e.g.

```
import math

predict_size_validation = int(math.ceil(nb_validation_samples / float(batch_size)))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `__future__` module to get python 3 behaviour, i.e.

```
import math
from __future__ import division

predict_size_validation = int(math.ceil(nb_validation_samples / batch_size))
```

Yet another solution is to rely on the integer division to do the computation (instead of relying on math.ceil):

```
predict_size_validation = nb_validation_samples // batch_size
if nb_validation_samples % batch_size != 0:
    predict_size_validation += 1
```

For more information on the python 2 floating point division, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Comment: Thanks! Now the result is 799, I will run the script again and see if it works. Saving the bottleneck features takes a little time, I will let you know how it goes!