# Pycharm python2.7 math

Tags: python-2.7, math, pycharm

I want to divide

```
300/266336
```

my console responds 0 even if I do

```
x = 300/266336
print "%.12f" % x
```

the answer is 0.000000000000
I know that the answer is 
0,0011263967319476
What is wrong?
How to do this in console, and why does it not work in file.py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's problem with python2. It will always give you an integer in this case. If you want to see float you have to use:

```
>>> float(300)/266336
0.0011263967319476151
```

Python 3 handles this more smoothly.

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 300/266336
0.0011263967319476151
```

Answer (score 1):

... or just say 300./266336 if working with literals (dot behind 300).