# Float number not working/printing in python

Tags: python, floating-point

So I am having a really weird issue here. I am not new to python but this type of scenario I haven't faced before. In my own k-nearest algo I have 2 variables i.e. correct and total. The value of correct varies from 133 to 136 and that of total is fixed i.e. 199, but when I print their division it gives me 0. Here is what I am doing:-

```
print(correct)    #prints 133-136
print(total)      # prints 139
print("Accuracy: ",correct/total)   #prints 0   # have tried // also
```

Since, I am dealing with accuracy and precision here so I need the result to be 0.95 to 0.97 and not 0, please help me fix this situation.
I am using python 2 and have tried print("Accuracy: ",float(correct/total)) which didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am......

Comment: Please specify which version of Python you are using. If you are using Python 2 you need to explicitly call `float` on your ints.

Comment: It isn't the duplicate, i said I have done both, both doesn't work.

Comment: @AsimRaja just look at the answer given and the comment I left. That is pretty much the issue you are facing.

Comment: @idjaw thanks it helped!!

Comment: You could also do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0) if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using python 2. Try this:

```
float(correct)/total
```