# regarding printing out the floating number with correct digit values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have two variables, `np.sum(train_y)` and `train_x.shape[0]`. When printing them separately, they are:

```
print('np.sum(train_y) ',np.sum(train_y))
print('train_x.shape[0] ',train_x.shape[0])

('np.sum(train_y) ', 398)
('train_x.shape[0] ', 213605)
```

However, their computed ratio is printed out as 0 instead of 0.00186.

```
print('np.sum(train_y)/train_x.shape[0]  ',np.sum(train_y)/train_x.shape[0])


('np.sum(train_y)/train_x.shape[0]  ', 0)
```

How can I get the value computed correctly?

Comment: `np.sum(train_y)/float(train_x.shape[0])` py2 uses floor division

Comment: `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Comment: Dear All, many thanks.