# Same code for python 2 and 3 gives different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the issue that I run python 3 on my client and the server where I execute the programs run python 2.

So I set up the following script:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt, exp
from datetime import datetime
def dateSmoother(a, b):
    #Format the date
    a = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")
    b = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d")
    diff = (a-b).days

    return exp(-(diff/h_date)**2)

def timeSmoother(a, b):
    # Since we only got readings from two different times
    # We first check to see if they are the same
    if (a==b):
        return exp(-(0/h_time)**2)
    else:
        return exp(-(12/h_time)**2)


h_date = 30
h_time = 12
a = "2013-11-01"
b = "2013-11-13"
print(dateSmoother(a, b))
print(timeSmoother("06:00:00", "06:00:00"))
print(timeSmoother("06:00:00", "18:00:00"))
```

When I run it locally with python 3 I get the following output:

```
0.8521437889662113
1.0
0.36787944117144233
```

However, when I run it on the server I get:

```
0.367879441171
1.0
0.367879441171
```

Comment: if you have python 2 on the server `diff/h_date` will be integer division (i.e. `//` in python 3); in python 3 this will return a float (`diff/float(h_date)` should make that part work as expected with both interpreters).

Comment: Also in the second function where you are returning the value

Comment: @Rahul in the if/else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in the division here `diff/h_date`

From the details mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0) here or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) here

- In Python2.7, division of two ints produces an int

```
>>> -12/30
-1
```

- In Python3,  division of two ints produces an float

```
>>> -12/30
-0.4
```

So depending on what you want

- If you want a float for both cases, import `from __future__ import division` in Python2.7,

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> -12/30
-0.4
```

- If you want a int in both cases, perform integer division `//` in Python3

```
>>> -12//30
-1
```