# Python division returning incorrect result

Tags: python, division

I want to write a function that takes in 2 values and calculates whether the division is an integer, but i am having trouble handling the case when say 5.1 and 0.1 is entered as the result is not 51 as expected.

```
def(a,b):
    return a/b.is_integer()
```

An alternative version i tried, to convert the values to decimals as well but still have the same issue.:

```
def(a,b):
    return Decimal(a)%Decimal(b) == 0
```

Comment: `Decimal` ? did you mean `float()` or are you using an `import`?

Comment: Should `a/b.is_integer()` be `(a/b).is_integer()`?

Comment: in python3 `a/b` always returns a float

Comment: @JuanC that's not correct, in python2, you will get an integer sometimes

Comment: @Chris_Rands Edited

Comment: @JuanC The logic is not correct, `2 / 1` returns `2.0` in py3, `2` in py2, this is not to do with floating point  representation, it's because in py3 they decided to return floats

Comment: Sorry then, I stepped out of my real knowledge zone, so I'll delete what I wrote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Answer (score 0):

This a problem of arithmetic precision in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (and other languages that use floating-point in computers), you could do one of two things in those case, the first case is assuming that it will be some limits and deal with it, or the second case is to use a specialized library that tries to deal with those problems.

A good compromise could be to use limited precision in your divisor, for example you could assume that any divisor `b` in your function could be a number with max 3 digits of precision, from like `5.999` or `0.001`, then you could first multiply dividend `a` and divisor `b` by `1000` and try to do the division there

Let's rewrite your function (and assume you are using Python 3)

```
def is_division_integer(a, b):
  a = 1000*a
  b = 1000*b
  d = a/b
  if type(d) == int:
     return True
  return d.is_integer()
```

The other alternative could be using a library like numpy, mpmath or others but probably you don't need them for general simple cases.