# python script failing on divide by zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, divide-by-zero

I am confused by Python (2.7) occasionally throwing a divide by zero error on the following code:

```
bat_delta = bat_start - batlvl
if runtime != 0 and bat_delta != 0:
    est_dur = round(((100/(bat_delta/runtime))/24),1)
else:
    est_dur = 'NA'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Isn't ```/``` Integer Division in Python 2? So if bat_delta < runtime, you're dividing 100 by 0 probably?

Comment: Thanks! It was an integer related issue. Changed to floating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)