# Canonical way to ensure float point division across py2 and py3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x, integer-division

I have a function that needs to support both py2 and py3, unfortunately.

Currently, there's a division op:

```
n = a / b
```

`a` and `b` are usually whole numbers, but represented as floats, but from what I can see there's no guarantee that either is a float, so the division could result in different behavior in py2 vs py3.

I plan on changing it to:

```
n = float(a) / b
```

which should guarantee float division in both versions. Is this the canonical way of doing this in python or is there a more accepted approach?

Comment: Note that there are edge cases where `float()` does not work and this answer has a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657822/218663